# RAML Traits definition

Tags: mule, traits, raml

I have a Mule Flow based on RAML that performs a sql query that returns 180 or so rows. I have the traits paging defined in my yaml. But when I run the flow seems to return all rows. instead of 10 rows at a time below is a fragment of my yaml. Do I need to implement paging on the back end also

```
/books/{topicName}:
    get:
        is: [ paged ]   
        responses:
          200:
            body:
              application/json:
                schema: !include books-output.json         
                example: !include books-example.json
traits:
  - paged:
      queryParameters:
          pagenumber:
            description: The page number of the result-set to return.
            type: integer
            minimum: 0
          pagesize:
            description: The number of rows in a page request.
            type: integer
            maximum: 10
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to implement paging on the back end also.  The RAML trait just defines the interface of how to pass the paging info to your API.